# onChangeText for InputField Causing Runtime Error in React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, formik, textinput

I'm using React-Native and "Formik" to try to create a text input field. I define a constant input field as the following: [image: textinput] and then try to embed it in a container using the following function: [image] The onChangeText line is what's causing the error; when I get rid of "username" the error disappears, but I need to call handleChange with that argument. (Additionally, whenever I try to call anything on the values parameter, it gives me the error that it is undefined).

Any advice?

Comment: did you try  {() => {handleChange("username")} ?

Comment: @JimmySoussan thank you! that fixed it. do you know why the values parameter would appear undefined? I.e if I do value=values.username it doesn't compile because it says values is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the longer answer is that onChangeText is requiring a callback function, (exactly like onClick for instance)

So basically you have to pass `{handleChange}` and not `{handleChange()}` or it will call your function each time it rerenders

You issue is that you had a parameter, in that case you can define an arrow function directly here like I told you in the comments and this arrow function will contain a call to your function with your parameter:

```
onChangeText={() => {handleChange("username")}}
```